# Closing resultSet and callableStatement

Tags: java, hibernate

Do I have to close `ResultSet` and `CallableStatement` if I use Hibernate? For example:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .connection()
                .prepareCall("{? = call PREQUEST.GetRequestList(?,?)}");
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.setString(2, sessionId);      
        cstmt.executeUpdate();
        cstmt.close(); // Closing
        return cstmt.getString(1);
```

Comment: Note: obtaining a [connection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#connection()) from Session is marked as deprecated ans scheduled for removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaDoc for the `Connection.close()` method starts with "Releases this Connection object's database and `JDBC` resources immediately instead of waiting for them to be automatically released."

Therefore, if you close() the connection, all the acquired objects, such as `Statements` and `ResultSets` will be closed.

However, if you use `connection pool`, the `close()` method returns the connection to the `pool` and doesn't actually close the connection. In this case dependent objects may be left open. In this case, I think, it is better to close them manually.